# Firebase build Error : Showing Recent Messages Undefined symbol: _kFIRLoggerAnalytics in swift5 on IOS 10.3

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase

there was no problem while I was working on the ios project.

However, there is a problem when trying to build on iOS10.3 What I have tested on a real device is 11.4. So far, there's no problem.

The 10.3 version is an issue.

**The contents of the error are as follows.**

[image: error]

```
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/***/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/****-aadwktpgbh*****f/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/FirebaseAuth/FirebaseAuth.framework/FirebaseAuth, building for iOS-armv7 but attempting to link with file built for iOS-arm64
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/****/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/*****-a***/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/FirebaseCore/FirebaseCore.framework/FirebaseCore, building for iOS-armv7 but attempting to link with file built for iOS-arm64
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/***/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/***-***/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/FirebaseCoreDiagnostics/FirebaseCoreDiagnostics.framework/FirebaseCoreDiagnostics, building for iOS-armv7 but attempting to link with file built for iOS-arm64
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/***/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/****-****/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/FirebaseInstanceID/FirebaseInstanceID.framework/FirebaseInstanceID, building for iOS-armv7 but attempting to link with file built for iOS-arm64
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/****/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/***-******/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/FirebaseMessaging/FirebaseMessaging.framework/FirebaseMessaging, building for iOS-armv7 but attempting to link with file built for iOS-arm64
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/***/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/****-***/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/GoogleDataTransport/GoogleDataTransport.framework/GoogleDataTransport, building for iOS-armv7 but attempting to link with file built for iOS-arm64
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/******/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/***-*****/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/GoogleDataTransportCCTSupport/GoogleDataTransportCCTSupport.framework/GoogleDataTransportCCTSupport, building for iOS-armv7 but attempting to link with file built for iOS-arm64
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/***/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/****-******/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Pods_*****.framework/Pods_********, building for iOS-armv7 but attempting to link with file built for iOS-arm64
```

This appears to be a `FireBase` related error. This issue occurs at 10.3. Not in 11.4. Test limits are present because the actual device version is limited.

- Xcode : Version 11.0
- ios6 12.4 : worked
- ios6 11.4 : worked
- iosX 13.0 : worked
- ios5 10.3 : get Error

How can I solve this problem??

Thanks in advance.

### I erased the cache and erased the drive data. And after building again, the error changed.

```
firebasecore/firebasecore.h' file not found
```

**my podFile**

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '12.0'

target 'testapp' do
    # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
     use_frameworks!

    # Pods for DeleteMe
    pod 'SwiftSVG', '~> 2.0'
    pod 'Toaster'
    pod 'BigInt', '~> 4.0'
    pod 'CryptoSwift'
    pod 'RealmSwift'
    pod 'web3.swift.pod', '~> 2.2.0'
    pod 'Firebase'
    pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
    pod 'Firebase/Auth'
    pod 'Firebase/Core' 
end
```

Comment: Try a clean build and wiping DerivedData.

Comment: Did you try with a 10.3 version and another Device!? PS: Messaging is not working on Simulator.

Comment: @A.Amini  There are no other devices available to test.

Comment: @PaulBeusterien Where can I erase my DerivedData?

Comment: rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/

Comment: @PaulBeusterien Error changed. Look at my question.